# ComboBox.Text to Label.Text

Tags: vb.net, combobox, label

The project is an alarm clock and the comboboxes select the alarm time which i want to print to label4 in the format hr:min:sec  AM/PM
i need to copy the value the is selected in my comboboxes and print them into a label with the format hr:min:sec AM/PM. This is what i have:

```
Label4.Text = (ComboBox1.SelectedText) & ":" & (ComboBox2.SelectedText) & ":"(ComboBox3.SelectedText) & " " & (ComboBox4.SelectedText)
```

' the rest of the combo boxes are similar

```
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("1")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("2")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("3")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("4")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("5")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("6")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("7")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("8")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("9")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("10")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("11")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("12")
    'ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = vari1
    ComboBox1.Update()
```

Comment: What are your combo boxes selecting? is cbo1 = hr? then cbo2 = min then cbo3 = sec?

Comment: Yes, cbo1 can select 1-12, cbo2 can select 00-59, cbo3 can select 00-59 and cbo4 can select AM or PM

Comment: Ok so what is wrong with what you currently have? what does label4.Text equal with the code above?

Comment: ObjectDisposedException was unhandled

Comment: Will need you to post more code. Where are you setting label4.text, in what method?

Comment: i have included the code for the combobox1 the other boxes are the same

Comment: I know this isn't really related to the question, but that seems a painful way for a user to pick the time. Why not use the DateTimePicker and set it to only accept time. See [DateTimePicker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: ok, how do i set it to only accept time?

Comment: If you read the MSDN documentation that i linked to, it tells you. set it by: `timePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time` then you can set a custom format if you need to

Answer (score 0):

Just as you said yourself in the title, you should be using `Text`, not `SelectedText`.  `SelectedText` is NOT the same as `SelectedItem`.  It's the same as the similarly-named property of a `TextBox`, i.e. the part of the text that is highlighted.  You're also missing an `&`, but that's not your core issue.

Comment: i have tryed Text and Selected Text both lead to the same result

Comment: Did you ever think to tell us what that result is?